# Is is possible to have internet facing Azure App Service next to non-internet facing App Service in same Service Plan?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-plan

I have Azure Service Plan. It based on linux. It is associating to a-vnet-prod.

I have web app in Azure App Service A, which has private endpoint. There is no access from internet.

Is it possible to add App Service B with public internet access under same Service Plan?

Is there any security risk that we have App A with no internet access in same plan with App B with internet access?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can deploy multiple web apps having of private and public endpoints (expect isolated plan which has dedicated virtual network) under the single app service plan within the plan limit as follows.

**Private Endpoint is available in public regions for PremiumV2-tier, PremiumV3-tier Windows web apps, Linux web apps, and the Azure Functions Premium plan (sometimes referred to as the Elastic Premium plan).**

[image]

Your private endpoint is associated with the web app and not with the App Service Plan unless it is an isolated plan.

References

- [Private Endpoints for Azure Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint)
- [Connect to a web app using an Azure Private Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-webapp-portal)